# Issues when attempting to install NAPALM for use with Ansible

Tags: python, networking, automation, ansible

I have tried to figure this out but have come to a dead end.
I am trying to install NAPALM on Fedora (release 21)

You can install either NAPALM as a whole 'napalm' or sub packages as needed- i.e

napalm-ibm
napalm-ios
napalm-junos
etc

When I run "pip3 install napalm" all the packages download/unpack however i seem to be getting specific errors related to pyangbind.

The same is true if i try to install a sub-package/

Details of the install log below
Any assistance would be much appreciated

```
[rbotham@ernie ~]$ pip3 install napalm
Downloading/unpacking napalm
  Downloading napalm-1.1.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm

Downloading/unpacking napalm-base (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-base-0.15.0.tar.gz (231kB): 231kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-base/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-base

Downloading/unpacking napalm-eos (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-eos-0.3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-eos/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-eos

Downloading/unpacking napalm-fortios (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-fortios-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-fortios/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-fortios

Downloading/unpacking napalm-ibm (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-ibm-0.1.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-ibm/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-ibm

Downloading/unpacking napalm-ios (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-ios-0.2.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-ios/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-ios

Downloading/unpacking napalm-iosxr (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-iosxr-0.2.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-iosxr/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-iosxr

Downloading/unpacking napalm-junos (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-junos-0.3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-junos/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-junos

    warning: no files found matching 'napalm_junos/utils/textfsm_templates/*.tpl'
Downloading/unpacking napalm-nxos (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-nxos-0.3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-nxos/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-nxos

Downloading/unpacking napalm-pluribus (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-pluribus-0.3.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-pluribus/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-pluribus

Downloading/unpacking napalm-panos (from napalm)
  Downloading napalm-panos-0.1.0.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/napalm-panos/setup.py) egg_info for package napalm-panos

    warning: no files found matching 'include'
Downloading/unpacking jinja2 (from napalm-base->napalm)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (263kB): 263kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking pyangbind (from napalm-base->napalm)
  Downloading pyangbind-0.5.8.tar.gz (46kB): 46kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/setup.py) egg_info for package pyangbind
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 274, in get_file_content
        f = open(url)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/requirements.txt'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        inst_reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in pip_reqs]
      File "/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/setup.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
        inst_reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in pip_reqs]
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1551, in parse_requirements
        session=session,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 278, in get_file_content
        raise InstallationError('Could not open requirements file: %s' % str(e))
    pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/requirements.txt'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 274, in get_file_content

    f = open(url)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/requirements.txt'



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/setup.py", line 8, in <module>

    inst_reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in pip_reqs]

  File "/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/setup.py", line 8, in <listcomp>

    inst_reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in pip_reqs]

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1551, in parse_requirements

    session=session,

  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 278, in get_file_content

    raise InstallationError('Could not open requirements file: %s' % str(e))

pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-fy54pkbj/pyangbind/requirements.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install under python3, Napalm does not currently support python 3.
https://github.com/napalm-automation/napalm/issues/199

Comment: fyi, neither does ansible at this time